# How can I catch that @Published has changed with combine ? (UIKit)

Tags: swift, uikit, combine

It takes data in my `@Published` variable in CarDetailViewModel, but I could not pass the data inside this variable to the variable in the ViewController.

**ViewModel:**

```
class CarDetailViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var carDetail: Car = Car(brand: "", features: CarFeatures(model: "", km: 0, year: 0, price: 0, image: "", gearType: "", fuelType: "", carVersion: ""))
    
    private var anyCancellable = Set<AnyCancellable>()
    var carSubject = PassthroughSubject<Car, Never>()
    
    func prepareCarDetail() {
        carSubject
            .sink {[weak self] car in
                self?.carDetail = car
                print("car: \(self?.carDetail)") // it is working.
            }
            .store(in: &anyCancellable)
    }
}
```

**ViewController:**

When the assignmentDataToUI function runs, the `label` on the screen is `blank`.

```
class CarDetailViewController: UIViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var brandLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var modelLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var gearTypeLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var fuelTypeLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var priceLabel: UILabel!
    
    var carDetailViewModel = CarDetailViewModel()
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        
    }
    
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        
        carDetailViewModel.prepareCarDetail()
        assignmentDataToUI()
        
    }
    
    func assignmentDataToUI() {
        brandLabel.text = carDetailViewModel.carDetail.brand
    }
}
```

Comment: Unclear what the question is. You are subscribed to carSubject, not carDetail.

Comment: When @Published variable inside CarDetailViewModel changes, I want to pass this change to CarDetailViewController.

Comment: But you are not doing so.

Comment: My code is working sir. Can you check ? I writed answer

Comment: If it's working what's the question?

Comment: The code above is not working. I have shared the working code below. @matt

Comment: Well you're still not doing what you said you wanted to do. If you're going to fetch carDetail manually what's the point of making it Published? The point of Published is to subscribe and you are not doing so.

Comment: so how Can I do this sir ?

Comment: Just as I said in my first comment and all the comments since then. You would _subscribe_ to the Published `carDetail`. If you're not going to subscribe to it, there's no clear reason to make it a `@Published` property. It also isn't clear (to me at least) why CarDetailViewModel is an ObservableObject.

Comment: I tink I did sir. Can you check my answer.

Comment: There you go, that's better. But of course this is trivially obvious so it's still hard to see what the question is for.

Comment: If the question I asked is wrong, I will delete this question.

Answer (score 2):

I listened to carDetail in ViewModel with sink.

```
 carDetailViewModel.$carDetail
                .sink {[weak self] car in
                    guard let self = self else { return }
                    self.assignmentDataToUI()
                }
                .store(in: &anyCancelable)
```

Answer (score 0):

In ViewModel

```
 @Published var text: String = "befor"
```

In ViewController

```
private var cancellables = Set<AnyCancellable>()

......

viewModel.$text.sink { text in
   print(text)
}.store(in: &cancellables)
```